# What is the 5x5 equivalent of the 3x3 emboss kernel?

Tags: c++, image-processing

```
-2  -1  0
-1   1  1
 0   1  2
```

This is 3x3 emboss kernel. How should I write this in 5x5?

Comment: I'm not a graphics guy but wouldn't placing a ring of zeroes around the 3x3 matrix make it a 5x5 matrix equivalent to the 3x3 matrix?

Comment: @TedLyngmo When comparing 3x3 filters for 5x5 filters, the matrix elements of the 3x3 filters should be the same for the 5x5.

Comment: I was thinking that 5x5 emboss kernel I suggested would produce exactly the same result as the 3x3 kernel (and therefor be considered equal to it), but perhaps that's not how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, these filters take directional differences (see the wikipidea [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_embossing)).

We can decompose you filter into directions

```
0 -1  0        0  0  0       -2  0  0

0  0  0       -1  0  1        0  0  0

0  1  0        0  0  0        0  0  2
```

So, I think you can expand it over these 3 directions giving emphasis

```
0  0 -1  0  0        0  0  0  0  0       -2  0  0  0  0

0  0 -1  0  0        0  0  0  0  0        0 -2  0  0  0

0  0  0  0  0       -1 -1  0  1  1        0  0  0  0  0

0  0  1  0  0        0  0  0  0  0        0  0  0  2  0

0  0  1  0  0        0  0  0  0  0        0  0  0  0  2
```

So, the final kernel would be

```
-2  0 -1  0  0

 0 -2 -1  0  0

-1 -1  1  1  1

 0  0  1  2  0

 0  0  1  0  2
```

May be you can also try interpolating filter coefficients marked as x

```
-2  x -1  0  0

 x -2 -1  0  0

-1 -1  1  1  1

 0  0  1  2  x

 0  0  1  x  2
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution to fitting any lower-dimensional convolution kernel into a higher-dimensional matrix of the same rank is to surround it by zero weights. This is especially true when you're dealing with a concept like embossing, which is arguably more interested in immediate vector of change than the rate at which it is changing. That is, for this embossing matrix,

[image: 3x3 embossing kernel]

You could equivalently use this in 5 x 5:

[image: 5x5 expansion of embossing kernel]

Granted, this will get you a different visual effect than anything with any part of the matrix filled in; but sometimes, especially with edge-detection, immediate clarity is more important. We aren't always displaying it. If this were something like a Guassian blur kernel, having a greater range could improve the effect, but embossing isn't that different conceptually from Sobel-Feldman and it may be better to keep it tight.